# How to extract text from a prc file

Tags: linux, debian

I'd like to get all text from a (DRM-free) `prc` file under Linux. Is there any tool for this? Unpacking an `epub` file is just an `prc`, so I hope there is a similar trick/tool for `prc` files too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KindleUnpack](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/KindleUnpack) works well. It is [downloadable from GitHub](https://github.com/kevinhendricks/KindleUnpack).

See also: [KindleUnpack (MobiUnpack): Extracts text, images and metadata from Kindle/Mobi files](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=61986) at MobileRead Forums.

Answer (score 3):

What you're actually looking at is a PalmOS "executable" file format, which has (for reasons beyond my comprehension) been re-used as an eBook format for "Mobipocket". See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRC_(Palm_OS)) for the background and a low-level description of the file format.

Since you asserted that the source file is **not** DRMed, that means all the text is in there somewhere in a ready-to-be-converted format. So all you need is a library to read the data appropriately.

My favorite program on Linux for converting between different eBook formats (or out of the eBook formats entirely) is [Calibre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibre_(ebook_software)) -- it does support unencrypted `prc` files.

If Calibre itself can't extract the text to a format you can use, and can only convert it to formats you can't use, then I would recommend that you check out the low level libraries that calibre uses as dependencies to read `prc` files. You could then use sample code from that library to develop a tool to read the PRC data at a high level, determine where the text is, and write it to a file. It should be reasonably simple if you are a developer.

This is a good question. +1.